# Collectives icon has wonky borders

Tags: bug, status-review, tags, design, collectives

Just a minor CSS issue when adding collectives icons next to the tag list, the right (and sometimes bottom) borders have some color leak (at least in Edge) when the site is in dark mode.

You can find the following example using [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=identity+server+MobaXterm) (until the question is deleted):

> [image: wonky border on search page]

If you click through to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75083249/how-to-set-up-sql-for-identity-server-wso2), it looks great:

> [image: looking good on the question page]

But in fact the icon itself has this issue, as seen on [the page for the collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/wso2):

> [image: icon still has wonky borders]

The icon is inverted in light mode so the issue is only obvious in dark mode (and you may need to adjust your browser width to see it - it may very well have to do with odd/even viewport sizes, or min/max).

For OS/browser specifics: I see this in Edge 108.0.1462.54 on macOS Ventura. I cannot repro in Chrome.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 108, Windows 10, zoom range 100%-500%, any browser width...

Comment: @AndrewT. Agreed, seems specific to Edge (or, at least, _not_ Chrome).

Answer (score 8):

On Firefox (Windows 10), I don't see borders, but I do see a couple of stray pixels at each corner no matter what the zoom setting. The pixels show up whether I follow the search link or the question link in the OP's question. The icon on the collective's page looks fine, though.

[image]