# Make the spacing between the collective indicator and a tag the same as the spacing between tags in the question UI

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, collectives

I just noticed a spacing inconsistency and it's bugging me.

In the question post UI, `.js-post-tag-list-wrapper` contents are `li.d-inline.mr4.js-post-tag-list-item`, where the `mr4` class has `margin-right: var(--su4) !important`, and the content of those `li`s are `a.post-tag`, with `margin: var(--su2) var(--su2) var(--su2) 0` and `border-width: 1px` (for some reason my browser devtools show 0.8 in the box sizing inspector though), but `.themed.subcommunity-topic-avatar` has `.s-avatar.s-avatar__24.va-text-top.js-community-tag.m2.va-top`, where the `m2` class has `margin: var(--su2) !important`. `--su4` is `calc(4px * 1)` and `--su2` is `calc(2px * 1)`.

So (if I'm not making any mistakes) the space between the border-boxes of tags is `5px`, but the space between the border box of the collective avatar and the border box of the first tag is `2px`.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can it please be made consistent? <sup><sub>(sorry for being a whiny brat)</sub></sup>

Related question, but not the same: [Collectives icon has wonky borders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422634/11107541).

Related MDN page: [docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model).

Comment: This spacing inconsistency has been addressed. Thank you for this post!

Comment: @Berthold thank you all for addressing it :D

Comment: hmm. I wonder if I should blame caching for the fact that it doesn't seem fixed for me right now.