# Collective icons are causing unnecessary new lines

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, collectives

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-openai) on a Google Pixel 6 phone with Chrome:

[image]

Comment: potentially historically related: [Make the spacing between the collective indicator and a tag the same as the spacing between tags in the question UI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423566/11107541) (or not. I don't know)

Comment: From the HTML and CSS in this area it's unclear that their intent was as far as how things should flow, but I don't think it's doing what they would actually want. It is, however, doing what it should, based on the existing HTML/CSS. So, it seems like it would be good for SE to take another look at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug! We were able to adjust the styling on those tag elements and the icon so that the icon flows inline with the rest of the tags. It should be fixed on mobile now.

Comment: That works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKG1o.png thanks for fixing the bug so quickly!