# Collectives icon is slightly shifted to the top

Tags: bug, status-planned, tags, design, collectives

Collectives icons on questions list in the tag section are slightly shifted to the top:

> [image]

More closer look:

> [image]

Reproduced on iPadOS 16.6, Chrome 115.0.5790.130

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention, the issue seems to be most obvious on an iPad (vs desktop) but I can see the alignment method isn't quite right either way.  I've let the team know.

Comment: related: [Make the spacing between the collective indicator and a tag the same as the spacing between tags in the question UI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423566/11107541)